# netPeerTCPBinding - Does OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel broadcast?

Tags: wcf, broadcast, operationcontext

I found two sources that seem to be contradicting each other:

"When the service receives a call, OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel returns a channel to just that caller. It does not return a channel that broadcasts to all of the clients." - [What does "OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel" actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171405/what-does-operationcontext-current-getcallbackchannel-actually-do)

"First, after joining a mesh, the newly joined node will send out a one-hop message requesting a list of unique record identifiers for shared state records. All nodes in the mesh that are one hop away will receive this message. These nodes will then use the callback contract to reply directly to the mesh." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700336.aspx

Now, which of the two is true? And, if it is broadcasting, how can I respond to another client in the mesh directly without broadcasting?

Thanks in advance,

Lars